# Silverlight databinding doesn't work

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

Below you can see a part of my class definitions:

```
public class Package {
  public int PackageId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Member {
  public int MemberId { get; set; }
  public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public class MemberPackage {
  public int PackageId { get; set; }
  public int MemberId { get; set; }
  public DateTime DateSold { get; set; }

  public Member Member { get; set; }
  public Package Package { get; set; }
}
```

These are EF 4 model classes. I pull MemberPackage objects from WCF RIA services and bind them to a DataGrid on the UI. To show the package names I use a binding syntax shown below:

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Package Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Package.Name}" />
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Sold" Binding="{Binding DateSold}" />
```

Nothing comes up under the Package Name column but I can see the Date Sold values. What's going on here, doesn't it supposed to work this way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Page has its own DataContext and the DataGrid on the page is not related to page's DataContext. I am setting it's ItemsSource property.

Comment: I am creating a new question as the problem is not related to databinding. Thank you all who helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be that when you get the MemberPackages in the service/factory, make sure you have the .Include("Package") as below:

```
return this.ObjectContext.MemberPackages
                .Include("Package");
```

This should bring back the Package details as part of the MemberPackage and then your binding to Package.Name should work.

Answer (score 0):

It is something to do with the data context of the view - are you sure Package is a property on your view model (data context) and do the models implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: No Package is not a property of the DataContext. But the grid doesn't get it's data from the page's context. I am setting it's ItemsSource from the code after the data is loaded.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a mvvm framework it does all this wiring up for you i like caliburn micro for wpf/silverlight

Comment: Thanks for the tip but that's not an option at the current stage of the project :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `Path=` and have this:

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Package Name" Binding="{Binding Package.Name}" />
```

You don't need to specify the path.

If that doesn't work then you should need to make sure that the `Package` member of `MemberPackage` has the `[Include]` attribute in the server side definition. This will ensure that the whole hierarchy is serialised to the client. I didn't suggest this at first as I assume that your code was edited.

Comment: I already use Include and can see the Package property filled up at the server side.

Comment: It appears that the problem is not related to data binding. I can see that the Package information is pulled from the database but it is not passed to Silverlight for some reason. Debugging the Silverlight application revealed that Package object is null.